# How to convert dictionary list values uniformly in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring

I have a yaml file with a couple of fields that are lists.

It looks kind of like this:

```
key0: "value0"
key1: ["value1-0", "value1-1", "value1-2"]
key2: ["value2-0", "value2-1", "value2-2"]
key3: "value3"
```

This is naturally converted to a Python dictionary with the PyYAML library.

Eventually I want to get a string of keys and values smashed together as follows:

`--key0 value0 --key1 value1-0 --key1 value1-1 --key1 value1-2 ... --key3 value3`

I came up with a solution that is dependent on the fact that I'm dealing with lists but something bugs me and makes me want to ask if there is a more clean, generic and elegant way?

UPD: after @senchuk answer I wanted to make myself a little more clear.

The question is not about ANY solution. This is merely an opinion-based question for people who are more experienced with Python than I am. I'm constantly hearing about this "pythonic" way. This is what I'm looking for! Something with a hipster functional thingy would do. There's no limitation on data transformation whatsoever. If the best way is to convert all of the scalar values to lists and then convert everything to a string, so be it. I'm really curious how this is done today in modern Python.

Comment: What have yo tried? please share with us your code or any attempts you made

Comment: I did something very similar to the solution from @senchuk. I'm asking here for a way that seasoned Python developers would choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the dictionary to build a string. if the item is a list, you have to iterate through its elements.

NOTE: since dictionary is an unordered collection, the output may vary.

```
dict={"key0": "value0", "key1": ["value1-0", "value1-1", "value1-2"], "key2": ["value2-0", "value2-1", "value2-2"], "key3": "value3"}

s = ''
for k,v in dict.items():
    print(k, v)
    if type(v) is list:
        for elem in v:
            s+= '--' + k + ' ' + str(elem) + ' '
    else:
        s+= '--' + k + ' ' + str(v) + ' '

print(s)

>>> --key1 value1-0 --key1 value1-1 --key1 value1-2 --key0 value0 --key3 value3 --key2 value2-0 --key2 value2-1 --key2 value2-2
```

Comment: This is barely different from the code I wrote. I was thinking a little more "pythonic". This ```type``` thing bugged me. Hence, the question actually.

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer as unfortunately I haven't figured out a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have something that converts what you've got into a dictionary, then this should do what you want

```
d = {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}
stringFinal = ''
tempString = ''
for k, v in d.items():
    tempString = str(k) + ' ' + str(v)
    stringFinal ='--' + tempString + ' ' +  stringFinal
    tempString = ''
print(stringFinal)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't even work! Take a look at @chenchuk answer. Although his/her answer is not exactly what I'm looking for, it works.

Comment: I am sorry!! i did not realize you had lists as values in your dictionary, i thought you were only dealing with string values. Yes chenchuks solution works, and could you be more specific as what you mean by pythonic? As in more efficient?? I appreciate your response!

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about! I was thinking list comprehensions, itertools and so on. I'm not trying to overcomplicate things usually. But the moment I type ```if type(v) is list``` I think okay, there's another clearer solution. Usually I find one myself but this time I tried for an hour to no avail. All of the solutions I came up with were alleviating the fact that I'm dealing with lists.